# Adding module dependency in IntelliJ without the +/- buttons

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I'm trying to add a library project to my Android project in IntelliJ. I know how to do this: you click to add one from existing sources, then once you have the library, you go back to your project, hit the dependencies tab and then link to the newly imported module. Problem is, I can't see that plus button my screen. This is a terrible UI bug in IntelliJ. I'm on a 13" macbook and I just can't get to that button in any way. If I use a larger monitor, I can maximize the project structure window large enough so that it shows the +/- buttons. But as of now, there's no way to scroll or anything to reach those buttons. I've filed this as a bug.

Is there another way to do this?

Here's a screenshot for reference

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround for [this bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-83810) you can use keyboard shortcuts to access the hidden buttons.

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> for the <kbd>+</kbd> button and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+
  <kbd>Delete</kbd> for the <kbd>-</kbd> button (**Windows** keymap).
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> for the <kbd>+</kbd> button and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> for the <kbd>-</kbd> button (**Mac** keymap).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are two references inside the Android app module:

1. Add `android.library.reference.1=../AndroidTestLibrary` in the `project.properties` file. Increment the last number for more libraries. This file is part of the standard Android build.
2. Add `<orderEntry type="module" module-name="AndroidTestLibrary" exported="" />` to the `iml` file. The entry was the last one inside the `NewModuleRootManager` element.